# SQL SERVER: where clause doesn't work in some way

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a question regarding `SQL SERVER` `where` filter clause.

[image]

```
SELECT
    Person

WHERE
    region NOT LIKE '%France%'
    AND region NOT LIKE '%America%'
    AND Country NOT LIKE '%France%'
    AND COUNTRY NOT LIKE '%America%'

    OR Region IS NULL
    OR Country IS NULL
```

By using this code, it displays Joh/Lily/HU.

How can the result only appears results that not contain words 'France' and 'America'? The the result should be Lily/HU.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It shows Joh because you have 'or Region is null'

Comment: @Helena In where  you check Region field but passing country values to check

Comment: The example query you show is looking at the wrong field for "France".  But also your results aren't consistent with the example query and data (which should return all rows).  Please update your question to the **exact** query and data you are using.

Comment: @dan1111, the query doen'st return all rows.

Comment: `Joh` dose not have neither `France` nor `America` in `Region`, so it does satisfy your conditions. Try removing all `OR`s.

Comment: @Héléna the query you have shown above would return all rows for the data you have shown above.

Comment: Also note, country names are actually stored in `Country` field. Not in `Region`.

Comment: Hi @Ivan Starostin,sorry I missed 2 lines, I have added, there are 2 more lines edited as above.

Comment: `OR Region IS NULL  OR Country IS NULL` - that's why you have `Joh` in results. It was told in first comment.

Comment: @ Ivan Starostin, yeah I understand why Joh appears, but I don't want it to apear. Here is the problem.

Comment: Well, it will, until you modify your code as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of your comments:

> I don't want to display anything containing "France" in either Region
>   or Country column, but also displays those with NULL rows.

```
SELECT
    Person
WHERE
    ( (country NOT LIKE '%France%' AND country NOT LIKE '%America%')
     OR country IS NULL
    )
  AND 
    ( (region NOT LIKE '%France%' AND region NOT LIKE '%America%')
     OR region IS NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT Person
WHERE
region NOT IN ('France','America')
OR ( region IS NULL OR country IS NULL)
```

Comment: I missed 2 lines in my orinal question, I have updated it. Can I use where Region NOT IN ('%France%','%America%')  and COUNTRY NOT IN  ('%France%','%America%')  OR ( region IS NULL OR country IS NULL)?

Answer (score 0):

No you need to segregate the "AND" and "OR" condition carefully.also France is in Country not in Region

```
    Select Person
    WHERE (Country NOT LIKE '%France%' and Country not like '%America%') 
    OR (Country is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    SELECT
        Person

    WHERE
        ISNULL(Region, '') NOT IN ('France', 'America')
        AND ISNULL(COUNTRY, '') NOT IN ('France', 'America')
```